# What actions should be done to get binargs without EOS api abi_json_to_bin?

Tags: nodeos, keosd, api

I am writing java code for communication with eos network and now need steps which should be done for retrieving data in the bin format without help of the node. Unfortunately I have not found documentation steps and algorithms. Can somebody help me to understand conversion logic abi json to bin? It will be nice if you share link for docs and put actions with algorithms which is used in the conversion process.
I need this info for creation raw transaction and send it to the network.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `eos-abi-writer` module of `eos-jvm` provides an annotation preprocessor for writing Kotlin or Java objects to abi bytes.

- https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm/tree/master/eos-abi-writer